# How do I navigate from a fragment to an activity on ImageView click?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

I am a beginner in android development and I want to navigate to an activity from a fragment when an image in ImageView is clicked. My Java class does not let me declare variables to link to my XML file. Also, I am not sure as to in which java class I should be declaring my variables.

I have also tried writing the same code in my MainActivity but it still shows an error.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    edSheeranSongs = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ed_sheeran);
    justinBieberSongs = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.justin_bieber);
    shawnMendesSongs = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.shawn_mendes);

    edSheeranSongs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),SheeranSongs.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

I expect to go to another activity which I have already created called SheeranSongs, But I get an error message when I try to declare anything in a fragment

Comment: Can you update the post to include the error you're receiving?

Comment: put your oncreate code in onCreateView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inflate the view in `onCreateView` of the fragment and initilize views with the created custom view. Override `onAttach` to get the context of the activivty to which the fragment is attached to.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

private Context context;
  @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        edSheeranSongs = view.findViewById(R.id.ed_sheeran);
        justinBieberSongs = view.findViewById(R.id.justin_bieber);
        shawnMendesSongs = view.findViewById(R.id.shawn_mendes);

        edSheeranSongs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SheeranSongs.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much

Comment: Sidharath Aggarwal .Please mark the answer as correct by clicking the check mark next to it, thank you!

Comment: There is no need to get context by overriding `onAttach()` see my answer much shorter =) @SidharathAggarwal

Answer (score 0):

You should call `findViewById()` from the *inflated view* within `onCreateView` of the *Fragment*. Exapmle:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        edSheeranSongs = view.findViewById(R.id.ed_sheeran);
        justinBieberSongs = view.findViewById(R.id.justin_bieber);
        shawnMendesSongs = view.findViewById(R.id.shawn_mendes);

        edSheeranSongs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(requireContext(), SheeranSongs.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with fragment you can't call findviewbyid() in onCreate() as you do in Activity since the fragment is created in onCreate() but the user interface isn't drawn yet ([More about fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)). 
You can do it in onCreateView() or onViewCreated(). From my perspective, I do it in onViewCreated() so it looks a bit cleaner.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
}

public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ImageView edSheeranSongs = view.findViewById(R.id.ed_sheeran);
    ImageView justinBieberSongs = view.findViewById(R.id.justin_bieber);
    ImageView shawnMendesSongs = view.findViewById(R.id.shawn_mendes);

    edSheeranSongs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(requireActivity(), SheeranSongs.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```